# Decreasing function Mean Value Theorem proof

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and twice differntiable on $(0,1)$. Show that if $f'(x) \le 0$ and $f''(x) < 0$ then $f(x_2)<f(x_1)$ when $0\le x_1 < x_2 \le 1$.

Attempt :

Suppose  $f'(x) \le 0$ and $f''(x) < 0$ ,and  $0\le x_1 < x_2 \le 1$. For the sake of contradiction let $f(x_1)\le f(x_2)$.
Then $f(x_2) - f(x_1) > 0$ and $x_2 -x_1 >0$ so by the mean value theorem $\exists c \in (a,b)$ st $f'(c) = \frac{f(x_2) - f(x_1)}{x_2 -x_1 }$. Thus we see $f'(c) \ge 0$ so to avoid contradiction with our hypothesis we investigate if $f'(c)$ can be zero.

Essentially this is where I'm stuck.. how can I use the concavity condition to show this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f'(c)=0$ then $f(x_{2})=f(x_{1})$. Since $f'(x)\le0$ then $f$ is constant on $[x_{1},x_{2}]$. So $f''(x)=0$ in $(x_{1},x_{2})$. This is a contradiction.